# Meaning of "been" in context below

Tags: meaning-in-context, existentials

In the dictionary, the verb "to be" has the meaning *exist* and the meaning *occur/take place*. What is the exact meaning of *be* in sentence below?

> There have been enormous advances in technology.

Answer (score -1):

This is a passive voice construction.  It could also be written

> Enormous advances in technology have taken place.

Comment: As per my understanding, in passive voice, past participle form of the verb is used after has/have been. But past participle form is missing in the sentence.

Comment: English uses "be" and "have" in lots of ways, it's confusing.  "There have been 2 world wars" (= "2 world wars have taken place")  and "There has been only one Summer Olympics in Helsinki" are valid sentences too.

Comment: This is not a passive construction: "have been" is active present perfect. You are perhaps misled by the fact that it employs the existential construction *there BE*, which moves the semantic subject of the sentence into the predicate--but that's just information packaging.